# fgetscv, fwrite $var with delimiter character

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

i have a small problem with my fwrite().

```
$txt=fopen("$directory","w");   
if (($handle = fopen("$directory", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
...
...
```

There are no problem if i write:

```
fwrite($txt, "Hello;");
fwrite($txt, "Test fwrite;");
```

The output in the .csv file is like this:

> Hello | Test fwrite

The problem appears when I have a variable contains the delimiter character, but I do not want fwrite consider it as a delimiter.
I have try to use chr(59), but the problem is not solved.

For example:

```
$var = "hello;test;hello;";
fwrite($txt, "Test fwrite;");
fwrite($txt, "$var;");
fwrite($txt, "Hello;");
```

The output of i would like to have is:

> Test fwrite | hello;test;hello | Hello

Is possible do this without change the character delimiter ( ; )??

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 1):

Easier done via [fputcsv](http://docs.php.net/fputcsv).

If your field contains the delimeter character you have to enclose the value (by default with double quotes).

e.g.

```
"abc;def";"x";"y";"z"
```

Comment: There are no method for do it with fwrite? Thank!

Comment: Of course, you can write the enclosing characters with fwrite, too.

Comment: You mean do this? $var = "hello;test;hello;"; fwrite($txt, ""Test fwrite";"); ?? Thanks

Comment: Yes, i have try to do: fwrite($txt, "\"Test fwrite\";"); but the problem of the delimiter characther persist. You Make me an example ? Thank!

Comment: You'd end up doing more or less as fputcsv does, so why not just use fputcsv?